# How to output results using a pivot table in the database query? Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I created a sponsorship app and on the User account section I would like to show the user all the kids they are sponsoring. I created a pivot table to hold the relationship between the User and Kid.

I have 3 tables I'm using:

```
+---------------------+
| Tables_in_Database  |
+---------------------+
| kid_user            |
| kids                |
| users               |
+---------------------+

+-----------------------------+
|        users table          |
+----+------------+-----------+
| id | first_name | last_name |
+----+------------+-----------+
|  1 | John       | Smith     |
|  2 | Sally      | Doe       |
+----+------------+-----------+

+-----------------------------+
|        kids table           |
+----+------------+-----------+
| id | first_name | last_name |
+----+------------+-----------+
|  1 | Bobby      | Little    |
+----+------------+-----------+
|  2 | Sam        | Little    |
+----+------------+-----------+

+-----------------------+
|   kid_user table      |
+----+--------+---------+
| id | kid_id | user_id |
+----+--------+---------+
|  1 |      1 |       1 | Kid: Bobby | User: John
|  2 |      1 |       1 | Kid: Bobby | User: John
|  3 |      2 |       2 | Kid: Sam   | User: Sally
+----+--------+---------+
```

I'm to output to the User's Account page the kids they are sponsoring. (A User can sponsor the same kid multiple times due to sponsorship slots)

This is the error I'm receiving:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= `kids`.`id` =
>   ?' at line 1

**Controller Logic for outputting the results:**

```
  public function sponsoring() {
    $kids = DB::table('kids')
    ->join('kid_user','kid_user.kid_id', 'kids.id')        
    ->join('users','kid_user.user_id', 'user.id')        
    ->where('kids.id', '=', 'kid_user.kid_id' && 'kid_user.user_id', '=', auth()->id()) 
    ->get();
  return view('profile.sponsoring.index',['user' => Auth::user()], compact('kids'));
}
```

In my Kid model:

```
  public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withTimestamps();
  }
```

In my User model:

```
public function kids()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Kid::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```

On my View:

```
@foreach ($kids as $kid)
    <p>You are currently sponsoring {{ $kid->first_name }} {{ $kid->last_name }}</p>
@endforeach
```

I'm sure I'm making this much harder than it is, but after reading the docs, SO and Google I'm still confused.

---

**UPDATE**
I fixed my query to the following:

```
public function sponsoring() {
$kids = DB::table('kids')
->join('kid_user','kid_user.kid_id', 'kids.id')        
->join('users','kid_user.user_id', 'users.id')        
->where('kids.id', '=', 'kid_user.kid_id')->where('kid_user.user_id', '=', auth()->id()) 
->get();
    return view('profile.sponsoring.index',['user' => Auth::user()], compact('kids'));
}
```

I don't get any errors now, but I do not get anything returned to the page.

Using the debug bar this is the query result:

> select * from `kids` inner join `kid_user` on `kid_user`.`kid_id` =
>   `kids`.`id` inner join `users` on `kid_user`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
>   where `kids`.`id` = 'kid_user.kid_id' and `kid_user`.`user_id` = 1

---

**UPDATE 2**

I can retrieve the results on one child like this:

```
        public function sponsoring() {
$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
$kids = $user->kids()->first();
return view('profile.sponsoring.index',['user' => Auth::user(), 'kids' => compact('kids')]);
        }

@foreach ($kids as $kid)
    <p>You are currently sponsoring {{ $kid->first_name }} {{ $kid->last_name }}</p>
@endforeach
```

But if I use `$kids = $user->kids()->get();` It errors out. with no first_name in the view.

**Final Correct Answer: Using Dito Khelaia logic...**

```
        public function sponsoring() {
$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
return view('profile.sponsoring.index',['user' => Auth::user()]);
        }
// In View:
@foreach ($user->kids as $kids)
    <p>You are currently sponsoring {{ $kids->first_name }} {{ $kids->last_name }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: i didn't program in Laravel for some time now.. `->where('kids.id', '=', 'kid_user.kid_id' && 'kid_user.user_id', '=', auth()->id()) ` looks wierd... i believe it should be more something like `->where(array('kids.id', '=', 'kid_user.kid_id', 'kid_user.user_id', '=', auth()->id()))` or `where('kids.id', '=', 'kid_user.kid_id')->andWhere('kid_user.user_id', '=', auth()->id())`

Comment: @RaymondNijland that 2nd line helped, but it's not `andWhere` just `where` again... I think. Now I get the error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user.id' in 'on clause'` ?

Comment: @RaymondNijland that error `'user.id` was fixed using `'users.id'`  Note the s on users.  Okay now I don't get any errors, but nothing returns.?.?

Comment: You have three params in view? `return view('profile.sponsoring.index',['user' => Auth::user()], compact('kids'));` looking in the documentation it's two params `return view('admin.profile', $data);`  so i guess it should be `return view('profile.sponsoring.index',['user' => Auth::user(), 'kids' => compact('kids')]);`

Comment: Notice i re-editted `return view('profile.sponsoring.index',['user' => Auth::user()], compact('kids'));` into `return view('profile.sponsoring.index',['user' => Auth::user(), 'kids' => compact('kids')]);` in mine other comment after you editted the question.

Comment: Ok.. That takes me to my view, but gives me the error that `first_name doesn't exist on this collection instance` ... But first_name is in the Kids table column

Comment: try without using `compact()`? if it works never use it again

Comment: Error `Undefined variable: kids` after removing compact.

Comment: "Error Undefined variable: kids after removing compact" Let me guess you have accidentally run `return view('profile.sponsoring.index',['user' => Auth::user(), 'kids' => kids]);` instead off `return view('profile.sponsoring.index',['user' => Auth::user(), 'kids' => $kids)]);`

Comment: `return view('profile.sponsoring.index',['user' => Auth::user(), 'kids' => $kids)]);`   worked, but returned no results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Models:

```
class User
{
    public function kids()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany(Kid::class);
    }
}
class Kid
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

Retrieve Records:

```
$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
$user->kids();
```

Comment: @DitoKhelaia you answer helps, but I still get Error `Property [first_name] does not exist on this collection instance` I'm my debug bar it's showing all my user info and not the child info? Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: @echo $kids = $user->kids()->first(); u can see or. 
foreach($user->kids() as $kids){
    $kids['first_name'] or $kids[0]['first_name'] 
}

Comment: @DitoKhelaia if I do this `$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);` and

`dd($user->kids('first_name')->get());` This returns my sponsor kids correctly. How do I get that in the view?

Comment: @echo Please tell me if my answer is helpfull for you

Comment: @DitoKhelaia yes it is helpful, but please see my latest update to the question. Almost there i think.

Comment: @echo u can use foreach($user->kids as $kids)

Comment: @DitoKhelaia Got it! I made that painfully harder than it should have been. (Facepalm) ‍♂️

Comment: If your code looks hard, you do not do something well. <3